# How to make the two windows equal width when comparing files?

Tags: vim-windows, vimdiff

How to make the two windows  equal width when comparing files with command 
`vim -d file1 file2`?

[image]

How to make the two windows be equal width?

Comment: You can [make the widths equal but preserve pane heights](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/20158/8520), which is very useful when you have 3+ buffers open, like debugger, quickfix, or preview panes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can equalize the size of windows with `<c-w>=`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want the window widths to remain equal as you change the size of the Vim window, try this in your ~/.vimrc:

```
if exists("##VimResized")
    if &diff
        au VimResized * wincmd =
    endif
endif
```

Comment: Upvote for you, as you save me some keystrokes

Comment: Why not `set equalalways`?

Comment: Because I generally don't want my windows of equal width, but I do want them of equal width when comparing two buffers. Also, 'equalalways' doesn't keep the windows of equal width when resizing the Vim window.