# How do I make the current tab's windows equal width but leave their heights?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, vim-windows

I know `<C-w> =` equalises window sizes but I often want to keep the heights as they are. I have `set noequalalways` in my `.vimrc` as leaving it on ruins layouts when temporary windows open (like Tagbar). I thought there'd be a one-liner to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a plugin `~/.vim/plugin/equalise-window-widths.vim`.

```viml
nnoremap <Leader>= :call EqualiseWindowWidths()<CR>

function! EqualiseWindowWidths()
    let l:i = 1
    let l:n = winnr('$')
    let l:wfh = ['dummy']
    let l:wfw = ['dummy']
    while l:i <= l:n
        let l:wfh = add(l:wfh, getwinvar(l:i, '&winfixheight', 0))
        call setwinvar(l:i, '&winfixheight', 1)
        let l:wfw = add(l:wfw, getwinvar(l:i, '&winfixwidth', 0))
        call setwinvar(l:i, '&winfixwidth', 0)
        let l:i += 1
    endwhile
    execute 'wincmd ='
    let l:i = 1
    while l:i <= l:n
        call setwinvar(l:i, '&winfixheight', l:wfh[l:i])
        call setwinvar(l:i, '&winfixwidth', l:wfw[l:i])
        let l:i += 1
    endwhile
endfunction
```

[It's on Vim scripts](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5819) so you can install it with your preferred plugin manager. It doesn't add any mappings so you may want to add the example, above, to your `vimrc`.